# me dice "undefined" al imprimir este array, ¿por qué?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, revisión-de-código

La cuestión es que haciendo llamadas ajax a un php que me devuelve un array con cantidad y precio, pero no me deja recorrerlo con un `for` y mostrar sus valores ya que me dice `undefined`.

```
function Ftotal(id){
var cantidad;
var descripcion;
var precio;
var ide=id;
$.get("./php/getTotal.php?ide="+ide, function(data, status){
                if (status=="success"){
                    for (i=0;i<=data.length;i++){
                        alert(data[i].cantidad);
                        alert(data[i].precio);
                    }
                }
    });
}
```

Estos `alerts` me devuelven `undefined`, el array seria el siguiente:

```
[
  {"cantidad":"2","precio":"5"},
  {"cantidad":"2","precio":"6"},
  {"cantidad":"1","precio":"4"},
  {"cantidad":"1","precio":"6"},
  {"cantidad":"2","precio":"4"},
  {"cantidad":"1","precio":"22"},
  {"cantidad":"1","precio":"3"},
  {"cantidad":"2","precio":"6"},
  {"cantidad":"2","precio":"3"},
  {"cantidad":"1","precio":"6"},
  {"cantidad":"1","precio":"4"},
  {"cantidad":"1","precio":"4"},
  {"cantidad":"6","precio":"4"}
]
```

El php es el siguiente:

```
function getTotal($conexion) {
        $ide = $_GET["ide"];
        $sentencia = "SELECT cantidad,precio FROM linea_ticket INNER JOIN producto ON producto.idproducto=linea_ticket.id_producto WHERE id_venta='$ide'";
        $stmt = $conexion->prepare($sentencia);
// Especificamos el fetch mode antes de llamar a fetch()
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// Ejecutamos
        $stmt->execute();
// Devolvemos los resultados
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
        $conexion.close();
}
```

Y la verdad es que llevo aquí un par de horas y no sé porqué me sale `undefined` cuando en las anteriores que tengo me las muestra sin problemas.

Comment: Si hacés un `console.log(data)`, qué te muestra?

Comment: ¿Has llamado a la función en el fichero PHP?

Comment: Le haces un "echo json_encode(array)" cuando lo devuelves?

Answer (score 1):

Vale, una posible opción, muy utilizada a la hora de mostrar arrays u objetos es transformarlos en un objeto `JSON`, pues **JS** y **PHP** pueden manejar la información que proporciona este objeto. Para utilizarlo simplemente devuelve desde php el objeto, un error que tienes es que acabas la función con un return, utiliza echo, ya que necesitas escribir la respuesta, no puedes devolver algo equivalente a una variable. Otro error es que tienes esa funcionalidad del php encapsulada en una función, y no tienes nada que ejecute esa función, elimina la declaración de función:

```
        $ide = $_GET["ide"];
        $sentencia = "SELECT cantidad,precio FROM linea_ticket INNER JOIN producto ON producto.idproducto=linea_ticket.id_producto WHERE id_venta='$ide'";
        $stmt = $conexion->prepare($sentencia);
// Especificamos el fetch mode antes de llamar a fetch()
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// Ejecutamos
        $stmt->execute();
// Devolvemos los resultados

        $resultado = $stmt->fetchAll();
        echo json_encode($resultado,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
        $conexion.close();
```

O en su defecto crea una especie de controlador(dentro del mismo php):

```
if (isset($_GET['metodo'])){
     $metodo = $_GET['metodo'];
     $metodo();
}
```

Y así sí puedes crear la función como tal

Desde js deberías cambiar la url a la que llamas y la forma de obtener los datos (código orientativo):

```
 $.get("./php/getTotal.php?ide="+ide+"&metodo=getTotal", function(data, status){
       if (status=="success"){
       var json = JSON.parse(data);
       for (var clave in json){
          // Controlando que json realmente tenga esa propiedad
          if (json.hasOwnProperty(clave)) {
          // Mostrando en pantalla la clave junto a su valor
              alert("La clave es " + clave+ " y el valor es " + json[clave]);
             }
          }
       }
        });
    }
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.